# jQuery ajaxStop() increments and fires multiple times

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I have read a ton before posting this and tried what i could to get it to work.   SO basically I am trying to use ajaxStop() as a sort of hook to do stuff after all other jQuery ajax requests have been loaded so I can manipulate  and add more to it.

But It seems when I do use ajaxStop() it seems to execute my additional added on requests multiple times...

Now after a bit of trial and error.  I learned that this is because within my ajaxStop() function I am calling another ajax post to grab data once something has been clicked, to populate a pop up. I need this click event handler to be registered after all other ajax has been loaded...  Because if I take it out of the ajaxStop() method the multiplicity error goes away but if I refresh the content via ajax than the click event doesn't register anymore.  I am most likely going about this wrong but could use some help.  It's getting late and my brain hurts so I'll take a fresh look at it tomorrow.

```
jQuery('.content').one('ajaxStop', function() {

 setInterval(doPopUpOptionsMenu , 1000);
 return false;

 });
```

Inside of doPopUpOptionsMenu is another ajax call to grab the content for the option pop up.

```
  function doPopUpOptionsMenu() {
 jQuery(".activity-popUpMenu").one('click',function(e) {
 var activityId = jQuery(this).parent().attr('id').split('-');
 //code to grab options and show the user the Options box.

   jQuery("#optionsPopUpContainer").css({'display': 'block', 'position' :'absolute',   'top' : e.pageY , 'left' : e.pageX});
var myAjaxURL = "example.com";
  var jqxhr = jQuery.post(myAjaxURL, { menuOptions : true, id : activityId[1] } ,     function($response) {
 jQuery("#optionsPopUpContainer").html($response);
})
.success(function() { alert("second success"); })
.error(function() { alert("error"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });

 });
 jQuery(".activity_update").hover(
 function(){
 jQuery(this).children('.activity-popUpMenu').addClass('activated');

 } ,
function() {
 jQuery(this).children('.activity-popUpMenu').removeClass('activated');
 //jQuery(".activity-popUpMenu").unbind('click');
  });

 }
```

now the alert for this pops up twice on the first click as it should once for success and once for complete.  Than I click on the pop up options again and it pops up four alerts than eight than 16 and keeps doubling pop ups.  Like I said I imagined this is due to ajax within the ajaxStop call but how can i get around it or do something better...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to work with something after all ajax calls complete in the document use $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){handler}); It's probably not the best approach but it does work pretty well if you want to listen for all ajax to finish.

Comment: Yea but well it work if the document changes lets say i call ajax again after page loads to change the content and than want to call this pop up options ajax again.  Doesn't this only work once?

Comment: I thought that was what ajaxStop is for.  ajaxComplete is when one ajax call has been completed.  Also what I said above was incorrect.  It didn't change anything using document as the selector.

Comment: I used it more as a global listener than attaching anything. So you can do $.ajax(___) in your document ready $(document).ajaxComplete() will fire once $.ajax() in your document ready finishes. So lets say you have 10 ajax calls in document ready. Once they all finish $(document).ajaxComplete will fire once this 10 calls finish. Isn't that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Try $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
 doPopUpOptionsMenu();
 }); How it works it should wait until all of your ajax calls finish  then fire doPopUpOptionsMenu. I'm assuming your code executes before ajax actually finishes. What I'd do is to create global variable myInterval then in your call if it needs to be fired every second I'd first do window.clearInterval(myInterval) and then attach myInterval = setInterval(doPopUpOptionsMenu , 1000);

Comment: Also do you really need it to repeat every second? Wouldnt it be better to do a timeout rather than continuously fire the doPopUpOptionsMenu a second?

Comment: You may want to also stop click event from bubbling I have no idea what's your markup so this is a pure guesswork. You catch click event you can add e.stopPropagation() or e.stopImmediatePropagation();

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this post looking for an answer because I was having a similar problem. For my situation I am using `.load()` to load various files into my page. When I use Vic's example of `$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){ //my function });` , My function actually ends up running 5 times. I have 5 .load() requests. So it appears to me that `.ajaxComplete()` will run the function after each request.

For my solution I used...

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
   //my function

});
```

And it ran the function once, which is what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. All my ajax requests executed the code in ajaxStop. I had a few ajax requests on page load to build things up and those should be the only ones to use the ajaxStop call.
The solution I found was to unbind the ajaxStop function so it would run only once.

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    customFunction();       
    $(document).unbind("ajaxStop");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you track your AJAX requests in a queue, you'll be able to inspect the actual request that was made before $.ajaxStop fires. The catch is that you'll have to do something like put a doNotQueue property on your AJAX call so that you can exclude selected calls from being tracked by your queue.

This actually isn't too hard if you use the jqXHR object in $.ajaxSend. Here is some sample coffeescript code that should get you going:

```
$.xhrPool = []
# When sent, all ajax requests get pushed into the XHR pool so we can abort/access
# them if necessary.
$(document).ajaxSend((event, xhr, ajaxOptions) ->
  unless ajaxOptions.doNotQueue
    $.xhrPool.push(xhr)
)

# Whenever an ajax call completes, remove it from the queue and then perform the
# desired operation if the queue is empty.
$(document).ajaxComplete((event, xhr, ajaxOptions) ->
  index = $.xhrPool.indexOf(xhr)

  # If this is a request being tracked by the queue, remove it from the queue
  if index > -1
    $.xhrPool.splice(index, 1)

    # If the queue is now empty then all ongoing AJAX calls we want to track 
    # have finished.
    if $.xhrPool.length == 0
      # Perform your desired action here, but make sure that if you make an AJAX
      # call you include the doNotQueue property. Note that this will fire every
      # time your queue runs out, so if you want to do something only once globally,
      # you'll have to keep track of that yourself.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, the *`async`* property is NOT set to `false`.

...something which I had been overlooking all the while.